# is it a routing loop? nodes cannot communicate

Tags: linux, networking

in picture case 1, all the network nodes are able to ping each other,
adding another node as in picture case 2, I start having a problem

case 1: [image: CASE 1] case 2: [image: case 2]

- machine h1 is acting as a router with two ethernet cards.
- h1 is connected to h2 via a switch,
- h1 is connected to machine h3 directly via an ethernet port with a cross cable and
- h3 is connected to h4 via a switch.

settings on h1 are

```
#ip addr add 172.16.192.1/22 dev eth0
#ip addr add 172.16.131.254/25 dev eth1
#ip forwarding is set to 1 in /etc/sysctl.conf
```

settins on h2 are

```
#ip addr add 172.16.192.2/22 dev eth0
#ip route add 172.16.131.128/25 via 172.16.192.1
```

settings on h3 are

```
#ip addr add 172.16.131.130/25 dev eth1
#ip addr add 172.16.131.129/25 dev eth0
#ip route add 172.16.192.0/22 via 172.16.131.254
```

settings on h4 are

```
#ip addr add 172.16.131.131/25 dev eth0
#ip route add 172.16.192.0/22 via 172.16.131.254
```

if one looks at the pictures of case1 and case2, it will be noticed that in case two node h4 was added, doing this machine h2 cannot ping machine h3 anymore, but in case 1 the ping was possible.

Now please don't tell me to change the network topology. It has to be exactly like this..and a condition is that a bridge cannot be used!

I'm wondering if there is a sort of a loop because in the routing table of h3 it has two entries to it's own subnet via both eth0 and eth1.

Anyway how can I make h4 be able to ping h2? with this exact same setting?

Answer (score 1):

There's no loop, quite the opposite.

The first problem, when you have a router "in the middle" of a subnet, is that its neighbouring devices are unable to send ARP queries through it. In your case, h1 thinks that h4's IP address is "local" on eth1 (because the subnet mask says so) and makes an ARP query for it, but ARP queries cannot cross routers – and even if they did, the result would be unusable because packets to h4's MAC couldn't cross a router either.

(And if *they* could cross a router, then it would no longer be a router: it would become a bridge. You said you don't want a bridge.)

Normally, to solve this, the h1–h3 and h3–sw–h4 connections need to be distinct subnets.

To solve this without changing subnets, you need to enable "proxy ARP" on the router h3 in the middle. It will answer h1's ARP queries meant for h4 with *its own* MAC address (and will do the same with h4's ARP querires meant for h1).

Proxy-ARP is a built-in kernel feature, but if it's too limited or inflexible, it can also be performed by a userspace daemon (parpd, parprouted).

---

The second problem, when you have two routes for the same subnet, is that the OS doesn't know *which* route to use – it always picks the same one, regardless of which interface the device is behind. In your case, most likely the ping replies always go through eth0, even though the gateway towards h2 is on eth1.

If you know upfront which devices are on which side, you can add more-specific static routes for them (and delete all-but-one subnet routes):

```
# ip route del 172.16.131.128/25 dev eth0
# ip route add 172.16.131.131/32 dev eth0
```

(You can simplify this by directly configuring the eth0 IP address as a /32 instead of a /25.)

To automate this, you can also use daemons like "parprouted" which perform ARP proxying and automatically add host routes corresponding to ARP responses.